# Retaining georeferencing information from CAD when opening in another mxd?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, georeferencing, arcgis-10.6, cad

I georeferenced about 150 CADs, updating the georeferencing as I work. I created a new mxd using the same base layers and added one of the CADs that was georeferenced but it did not retain the location, rotation, or scaling information.

I am using ArcGIS Desktop 10.6.

What am I doing wrong?

I tried saving the georeferencing in the project folder, and then tried saving it in the root CAD folder. Both options gave me the same result. It opens up, but not where I georeferenced it.

Comment: A world (.wld) file (text file) is required > http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/manage-data/cad/world-files-for-cad-datasets.htm

Comment: You can create a single universal world file (esri_cad.wld) for a folder, http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/manage-data/cad/about-georeferencing-cad-datasets.htm

Comment: Mapperz wins a cookie. Thanks! Problem solved.